# Extracting range of values from a tibble in R

Tags: r

I have a `df` converted to a `tibble`. Let's say I am interested to extract a range of values from the `Week` column say between rows `1` and `3`. In case of a `df` I can simply do `df[1:3, 7]`, but how can I do this in case of a `tibble`?

Code

```
   library(tidyverse)
    
    # Create sample data
    Date = c("2014-04-08", "2014-06-04", "2014-04-30",
                  "2014-05-30", "2014-05-01")
    lat = as.numeric(c("45.53814", "45.51076", "45.43560", "45.54332",
            "45.52234"))
    lon = as.numeric(c("-73.63672", "-73.61029", "-73.60100",
            "-73.56000 ", "-73.59022"))
    id = as.numeric(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
    
    
    # Create a df from the above columns and add date columns
    df = data.frame(id, lat, lon, Date)
    df$Year = lubridate::year(df$Date)
    df$Month = lubridate::month(df$Date, label = TRUE, abbr=FALSE)
    df$Week = lubridate::week(df$Date)
    df$Date = as.Date(df$Date)

# Create a tibble
dft = as_tibble(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[[` or `$` with name to get the column as a vector - `tibble` by default use `drop = FALSE` whereas `data.frame/matrix` have `drop = TRUE` when there is a single column/row

```
dft[1:3,][[7]]
[1] 14 23 18
dft[1:3,]$Week
[1] 14 23 18
```

---

Or if we want to use `tidyverse` approaches, use `pull`

```
library(dplyr)
dft %>%
   slice(1:3) %>%
   pull(7)
```

As @Baraliuh mentioined in the comments, extraction methods for `tibble` are mentioned [here](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/subsetting.html)

Comment: Maybe could be nice to attach the reference page for tibble subsetting? https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/subsetting.html